# Keeping button state on page redirect

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to keep the properties set in :hover , when you are at the address of the clicked button?

To clarify let's say I have a button that turns red when I click it and it redirects to mysite.com/buttonPage.html. On buttonPage.html can I keep the button red?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, on the server side you add a class to the button/link if it's destination matches the current page. Something like (in PHP):

```php
<a href="<?php echo $url; ?>"
<?php
    if ($url === current_url()) echo ' class="current"';
?>
>Link Text</a>
```

Then add the `.current` selector to the styles for `:hover`.

This doesn't actually "maintain state", but should do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

**No.** The only way to keep the button red is if you have some sort of external persistence. The browser will not handle this persistence for you.

Instead of redirecting to another page, you could instead do AJAX rendering within the current page, in which case your button would continue to be styled red. Upon redirecting to another page, though, *you will lose state*.

You can tie the rendering of the page to persistence in any number of ways, say a database that tells you whether you voted up my answer. If you did, then somewhere in your view logic you will render the upvote button orange.

Comment: Okay so in the style sheet just have a special id for that certain webpage?

Comment: @jaiesh Look at my third paragraph for hints about how to do persistence.